# ASPNET MVC 3 and google maps not working, giving 404 not found using IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3, iis-7.5

I've an ASPNET MVC 3 project and I'm using GoogleMaps api v3, I'm developing with Visual Studio 2010.

My problem is that when I was using the Visual Studio 2010 webserver googlemaps worked OK, but when I moved to IIS 7.5 I'm trying to get a map and I'm receiving a lot of 404 not founds.
For example (from Fiddler):

63  404 HTTP    khm0.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415914&y=2527608&z=22&token=129508&style=api%7Csmartmaps   11.888      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
64  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415913&y=2527607&z=22&token=77236&style=api%7Csmartmaps    11.887      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
65  404 HTTP    khm0.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415914&y=2527606&z=22&token=35196&style=api%7Csmartmaps    11.887      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
66  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415915&y=2527607&z=22&token=87468&style=api%7Csmartmaps    11.887      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
67  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415913&y=2527606&z=22&token=30080&style=api%7Csmartmaps    11.887      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
68  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415913&y=2527608&z=22&token=124392&style=api%7Csmartmaps   11.888      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
69  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415915&y=2527606&z=22&token=40312&style=api%7Csmartmaps    11.887      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740
70  404 HTTP    khm1.googleapis.com /kh?v=90&hl=es-AR&x=1415915&y=2527608&z=22&token=3553&style=api%7Csmartmaps 11.886      text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:4740

Any ideas what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of warning about 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html.
ANy ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker reminded me that developer license is not guaranteed to have high availability, so maybe that's the reason of why I'm getting 404's, despite I see the maps.

Answer (score 2):

We are experiencing the same problem.  One of our developers found this link:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/10/introduction-of-usage-limits-to-maps.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+GoogleGeoDevelopersBlog+%28Google+Geo+Developers+Blog%29

We're looking into whether licensing will be needed to avoid this problem.